# In the Star Trek Universe, can a non-cloak capable ship hide within another ship's cloak?

Tags: star-trek, cloaking

According to '[Star Trek: Klingon Bird-of-Prey Haynes Manual](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/star-trek-ben-robinson/1110866780?ean=9781451695908)', the cloak works by generating a quantum phase bubble around the ship.

It's been demonstrated that non-warp ships can in fact 'borrow' another ship's warp capability by tucking inside that ship's warp field. By the same token, has it been demonstrated or is it possible to use that same technique to 'borrow' another ship's cloak by tucking inside this quantum phase bubble?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, a cloaking shield can be extended around a non-cloak capable vessel.

The cloaking device is an offshoot of shielding technology and can be tied into either the deflector shield or a ship's main shield and hence can be extended.

In TNG: "[Devil's Due](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/187.txt)", the following exchange takes place;

> **PICARD :** *She has a Romulan cloaking device?*
>
> **GEORDI :** *More likely, a bad copy of one. We picked it up through a wavelength stretchout...*
>
> **PICARD :** *And the Enterprise?*
>
> **GEORDI :** *Exactly where it's supposed to be*. **Ardra extended her cloaking shields around it...**

In the episode VOY: "[Tinker, Tenor, Soldier, Spy](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/603.htm)", the aliens are using a **cloaking field** which appears to extend to cover multiple vessels;

> **JANEWAY:** *I don't want to hear it. However, I would like to know why you've disobeyed my direct order*.
>
> **EMH:** *I can prove it to you. The alien told me how to reconfigure our sensors to compensate for their cloaking field.*
>
> **KIM:** *He's right. I'm picking up three ships out there. Distance six hundred million kilometres, headed right for us.*

This obviously applies to **[standard cloaks](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cloaking_device)**. There's no in-canon way to tell whether this also applies to *exotic* cloak types such as the one used to cloak an entire planet in TNG: "[When The Bough Breaks](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/When_The_Bough_Breaks_%28episode%29)" or the Trans-phasic cloak used by the Enterprise in TNG: "[Pegasus](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Pegasus_%28episode%29)"

Comment: The Voyager one sounds a bit like it might have been bad wording as well. Like a skipped word: *"[...] compensate for their cloaking field [technology]"* It's more obvious for the TNG episode though to be indeed the case.

Comment: @Mario - A cloaking field sounds different from a cloaking shield.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. Missed that detail.

Comment: @Richard -Good research. Now that you bring that episode (TNG 4x13) to light, it reminded me of something I noticed about it at the time. She cloaked the Enterprise without the Enterprise noticing it nor did they become aware of her ship when she did. This is secondary to the question or your answer, just interesting.

Comment: Also, the Enterprise is a pretty big ship for such a comparably small ship such as hers to extend a cloak around.

Comment: @Morgan - For the record, her cloak was quite easily penetrable when they actually started looking for it. It was only because of the "surprise factor" that she got away with it at all.

Comment: I'd imagine that if the Enterprise-D had entered Aldea's cloaking field, they would also be cloaked, just as the NX-01 did when it entered the Delphic Expanse Sphere's cloaking field. However, it probably wouldn't work with holographic cloaks (like those used by Federation observation stations and isolation suits) or interphasic/phase-variance-based cloaks, which seem to cloak objects directly rather than a region of space around the object.

Comment: @Richard It appears that there is more variations of the cloaking technology than I was aware of.

Comment: @Richard:   It seems pretty obvious that the planetary cloak would hide a ship parked on the surface as well.   This doesn't really need speculation.